# Strange force close on acore when adding a home screen shortcut

Tags: android

I want to add home screen shortcuts to individual chat rooms, in my app.  Here's my code to do so:

```
Intent roomIntent = roomIntent(room).putExtra("shortcut", true);

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, roomIntent);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, room.name);

Parcelable resource = Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(this, R.drawable.icon);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON, resource);

setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);       
finish();
```

When I go to add the shortcut to my home screen, I get a Force Close, not on my own process, but on com.android.acore(!).  I've run the debugger and verified that my code gets executed all the way to the call to finish().

If I do this instead for the EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON:

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON, R.drawable.icon);
```

It works fine and places the shortcut, and the shortcut behaves correctly -- but of course the shortcut has the stock Android icon, not mine, since this isn't the proper way to specify the icon.

When I look at the source code of other apps that have done this, and at [the one example](http://dev.android.com/guide/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/LauncherShortcuts.html) of it in the official Android reference area, my code looks identical.  My icon's a standard 48x48 png that I use for the app's main icon, without problems.  I've verified this problem on an emulator running stock 1.6, haven't tested other versions.

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.  Any ideas?

Comment: Do you execute your code on the emulator ? Most of time when I deploy my app on the emulator I got some 'Force close' on android.acore or else. But it doesn't impact my application and I don't get them when I debug on a real device. I just ignore them...

Comment: I've also tested this on my phone, which is running the latest CyanogenMod.  It gets the same error. I went to the emulator to make sure that it wasn't some CyanogenMod-specific thing.  The error is also 100% consistent in both cases, so I don't think it's something specific to a device or to an emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Javadoc for [`ACTION_CREATE_SHORTCUT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CREATE_SHORTCUT) says that you should use `EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE` for `Intent.ShortcutIconResource` objects, rather than the `EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON` key you're using, which is used for directly placing a `Bitmap` into the `Intent` extras.

You should probably also file a bug for the crash on the [Android bug tracker](http://b.android.com/), as getting something like this wrong shouldn't bring down acore.

Comment: Yes, of course. I kept comparing my code with other people's code, yet missing that change.

It was different because I copy/pasted the shortcut code originally from another app of mine, which actually does place a Bitmap directly into the extras.

THANK YOU!

Comment: I followed your advice and filed a bug:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5791